# trigger.io - hide a html element on touch/tap event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, trigger.io

The problem seems simple enough yet it is not working.

What I want is a div to hide on tap. I currently am using jQuery but if anyone know have to do this in a more native manner id love to do that!

I have tried using this but it did not work

```
$(".event_image").on('tap', function(e) {
    $(this).hide()
});
```

anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't have anything for touch/tap events, but you can easily build your own by using these:

```
touchstart
touchmove
touchend
touchcancel
```

More information available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

or you can use a plugin such as [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) which supports touch events & much more!

Answer (score 1):

Could you just do a click event? They're basically the same.

```
$(".event_image").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there will be a slight delay until the `click` event is fired, because many mobile browsers wait for gestures in between. There are several scripts to remove this delay while still using onClick: http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone